# How to put my check box under my text fields in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a text field to represent a name, and a combobox for registration type.  Then, next to that I have a check box, but it's supposed to be underneath the other two fields.  Here is what I have coded:

```
   public RegPanel()
   {
      //create a new panel
      new GridLayout(2,1);  
      //create one of two subpanels
      subPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      //create a textfield
      regTextField = new JTextField(20);
      //create a combobox and don't let anyone add to it
      regComboBox = new JComboBox(regOptions);
      //create a border for the subpanel      
      subPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Registrant's Name & Type")); 
      //add regTypePanel and regBox to the panel     
      subPanel.add(regTextField);
      subPanel.add(regComboBox);
      //create a second subpanel with a flowlayout
      subPanel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      //create a checkbox
      regCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Dinner and Keynote Speech");
      subPanel2.add(regCheckBox);
      //add the subpanels to the main panel
      add(subPanel);
      add(subPanel2);
   }
```

Any ideas what I am missing? Sorry for the crappy layout, I can't figure out how to fix the view.

So I realized I hadn't set the GridLayout right, so I changed that to "setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
But now on my gui, it totally screwed up the position of all the other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway `new GridLayout(...)` do nothing unless you use it in `setLayout(...)`.

You can try using Box.createVerticalBox() ([sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/BoxcreateVerticalBox.htm)) instead of GridLayout to have your components in vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are using

- RegPanel (which layout?)

  - subPanel (FlowLayout)

    - regTextField
    - regComboBox
  - subPanel2 (FlowLayout)

    - regCheckBox

Which layout does your main RegPanel have? It has the default JPanel layout (if RegPanel is a subclass of JPanel), which is a FlowLayout. So, your RegPanel shows the two subPanels besides each other, which looks similar as if you had only one Panel with all the components. So, your RegPanel needs a LayoutManager, too - the GridLayout(2,1) seems okay (if you don't want to align the components in the two lines).

---

In [my current project](http://www.fencing-game.de/), I'm only ever using `GroupLayout` (apart from one occasional BorderLayout). It takes a bit to get used to (and a wrapper class to make the code easier to write and read), but for such form stuff, it seems ideal (when limited to the build-in Layout managers).

Answer (score 0):

Also you might want to use a BorderLayout and realize that you nest one layout in another layout to achieve a different effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have to mention [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) here as a great all-purpose layout manager -- it is extremely flexible and easy to use once you get to know it.